# Does a continuous function preserve measurability?

Tags: measure-theory, functions

If $f$ is a continuous function on $X$ and E a Lebesgue measurable set, can we conclude that $f^{-1}(E)$ is measurable?

Comment: I presume $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous function between topological spaces equipped with their Borel $\sigma$-algebras?

Comment: I know that "The inverse image of any Borel set is measurable". But I want to see if the general case (any measurable) holds.

Comment: No.  See here for the standard counterexample: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104519/a-question-concerning-the-cantor-ternary-function

Comment: What do you mean by "the general case" here? What is the codomain of $f$ and what $\sigma$-algebra are you using on it?

Comment: Actually the example in the link provided by Chris is used to proof that "measurable" is really more general than "Borel": there is a measurable set $B$ such that its inverse image by a continuous map is not measurable so is not Borel. The same function in that post serves to show that measurability is not a topological property.